# How to set all .py files in Komodo Edit project to be recognized as Python 3 instead of Python 2?

Tags: python-3.x, komodo, komodoedit

I just recently started using Komodo Edit 10 and used an existing Django project which uses Python 3.6.x. I created a Komodo project (`.komodoproject` file) for it and updated the `Projects > Project Preferences > Languages > Python 3 > Use this interpreter` to point to my `conda` virtual environment. I've also added the `site-packages` directory to the `"Additional Python 3 Import Directories"` and so I was expecting code completion to work.

Now, when I open a `.py` file, like `models.py`, and start typing `from dj`, no code completion is done (I was expecting to get `django` drop-down). Then I noticed that in the open file, there's a drop-down to change the file type of the file (upper-right corner of editor). I changed it to "Python 3" and now completion works (yey!). So then I proceed to open the `views.py` file expecting code completion to work but it wouldn't, and I had to set the file type to "Python 3" before it worked.

Now, my question is if there's a way to batch change the file type for all `.py` files inside the project from "Python 2" to "Python 3"? Or do I have to tediously change the file type for each `.py` file manually?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the file association under Preferences > File Associations.